# Can anyone solve (s→p)→r, ~r, (p→q)→(t→r)//~t

Tags: logic

I've been at it for hours. The only tools I'm allowed to use are as follows:

Indirect derivation
Direct derivation
Conditional derivation
Modus ponens
Modus tollens
Double negation
Repetition

(s→p)→r
 ~r
(p→q)→(t→r)
//~t

Comment: I love it! They are like brain teasers. I wish they had them in the paper.

Comment: I can get pretty close but I'm having some trouble accomplishing a disjunction introduction to get (p → q) from ~p.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(s → p) → r, ~r, (p → q) → (t → r) : ~t**

```
{1}      1.   (s → p) → r                      Prem.
{2}      2.   ~r                               Prem.
{3}      3.   (p → q) → (t → r)                Prem.
{1,2}    4.   ~(s → p)                         1,2 MT
{5}      5.   p                                Assum.
{6}      6.   s                                Assum.
{5,6}    7.   p & s                            5,6 &I
{5,6}    8.   p                                7 &E
{5}      9.   s → p                            6,8 CP
{1,2,5}  10.  ~(s → p) & (s → p)               4,9 &I
{1,2}    11.  ~p                               5,10 RAA
{12}     12.  ~q                               Assum.
{5,12}   13.  p & ~q                           5,12 &I
{5,12}   14.  p                                13 &E 
{5}      15.  ~q → p                           12,14 CP
{1,2,5}  16.  ~~q                              11,15 MT
{1,2,5}  17.  q                                16 DNE
{1,2}    18.  p → q                            5,17 CP
{1,2,3}  19.  t → r                            3,18 MP
{1,2,3}  20.  ~t                               2,19 MT
```

*Abbreviations:*

```
&I = & Introduction
&E = & Elimination
DNE = Double negative elimination
MP = Modus ponens
MT = Modus tollens
CP = → Introduction
RAA = Contradiction
```

Comment: I'm not so sure this answers the proof using the limited rules of inference I've been provided with, but thank you! It's still very useful.

Comment: @user321275. I'm not familiar with the names of the rules you provided, but if you find a rule that doesn't conform to your constraints, let me know and I can update my answer.

Comment: @user321275. I added a list of abbreviations.

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you so much. I honestly don't think the question can be answered using the limited rules of inference I was provided. The entire class couldn't finish the proof under the restrictions. I think your answer outlines what I will be learning in my next class.

Comment: It looks like you're lacking a contradiction rule. Is that right? If so, I can try to do it without that.

Comment: Yes, I don't have Contradiction, → Introduction, & Introduction, or & Elimination. It's alright man, I think the teacher is trolling my class and just using this problem to introduce new rules of inference next class.

Comment: I did some checking, and it looks like Indirect derivation is the same as Contradiction or RAA. In virmaior's proof, he does the same thing but labels it "ID 9-13". As far as & introduction and elimination, that's just a trick to show that an implication is dependent on the antecedent; some might not consider it necessary. So it looks like my proof does conform to your constraints.

Comment: Well that's awesome! Thanks again, I really appreciate it. I'll definitely bring your proof to class on Wednesday and let you know what the professor says.

Answer (score 1):

It can be answered using the provided rules of inference: DN and ID can take the place of the missing RAA.

1) **(s → p) → r** --- premise

2) **~r** --- premise

3) **(p → q) → (t → r)** --- premise

4) **~(s → p)** --- from 1) and 2) by MT

5) **p** --- assumed [a]

6) **s** --- assumed [a1]

7) **~p** --- assumed [a2]

8) **~~p** --- from 5) and 7) by ID, discharging [a2]

9) **p** --- from 8) by DN

10) **s → p** --- from 6) and 9) by CD, discharging [a1]

11) **~p** --- from 4), 5) and 10) by ID, discharging [a]

12) **p** --- assumed [b]

13) **~q** --- assumed [c]

14) **~~q** --- from 11), 12) and 13), discharging [c]

15) **q** --- from 14) by DN

16) **p → q** --- from 12) and 15) by CD, discharging [b]

17) **t → r** --- from 3) and 16) by MP

> 18) **~t** --- from 2) and 17) by MT.